# I have Multiple keys in the dictionary want to point to the same value what can I do

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to Python,so I hope someone can help me,Thx!

The program

```
dict=(zip((3,4,5),('Spring','Spring','Spring')))
```

why can't I cut the Program like..

```
dict=(zip((3,4,5),('Spring')))
```

I have Multiple keys in the dictionary want to point to the same value
what can I do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dict has a `fromkeys` class method that does just what you want:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys((3, 4, 5), "Spring")
{3: 'Spring', 4: 'Spring', 5: 'Spring'}
```